# Force validation of entire form in AngularJS upon editing any portion of the form?

Tags: angularjs

I have a form in which the validity depends upon the relationship between multiple textboxes. For example, if there are three textboxes, then the form is valid only if each textbox's integer value is greater than the previous textbox's integer value.

I'd like to set up this form so that if the user edits any of the textboxes, the entire form revalidates.

I've tried setting up ng-change=revalidate() on all the textboxes, with the following:

```js
$scope.revalidate = function() {
    var formData = $parse('signals');
    var dataCopy = angular.copy(formData($scope));
    formData.assign($scope, dataCopy);
};
```

I hoped that copying and reassigning the form's data would trigger revalidation, but it doesn't seem to work. How would I achieve this?

Comment: Seems like a decent answer, if you don't get any responses and are allowed you should post as your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a directive. In that directive, I set up a $watch on the concatenated values of all the textboxes. Then when that $watch sees a change in any of the textboxes, it revalidates the element. Since this directive is applied to all my textboxes, the entire form revalidates when any one of the textboxes is edited.

If someone has a more elegant solution than this, let me know.

```js
link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
                // when any of the intervals for this signal change, revalidate this interval
                scope.$watch(
                    // loop through all the intervals for this signal, concatenate their values into one string
                    function() {
                        var intervals = [],
                            child = scope.$parent.$$childHead;
                        while (child !== null) {
                            console.log(child);
                            intervals.push(child.interval.end);
                            child = child.$$nextSibling;
                        }
                        return intervals.join();
                    },
                    function() {
                        validate(ctrl.$viewValue);
                    }
                );

                function validate(intervalDateTimeFromView) {
                    var valid = false;
                    // if this interval ends before or at the same time as the previous interval
                    if (scope.$$prevSibling && Number(intervalDateTimeFromView) <= Number(scope.$$prevSibling.interval.end))
                    {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('overlappingInterval', false);
                        return undefined;
                    } else {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('overlappingInterval', true);
                        return intervalDateTimeFromView;
                    }


                }

                ctrl.$parsers.unshift(validate);
                ctrl.$formatters.unshift(validate);

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect, but it's what I'm working on at the moment:

```
$element.bind('blur', function() {
    formCtrl[inputName].$dirty = true;
    $scope.$emit('validate-refresh');
});

$scope.$on('validate-refresh', function() {
    var control = formCtrl[inputName];
    if (control.$dirty) {
        control.$setViewValue(control.$viewValue);
    }
}
```